# How to merge two KML files of different sizes (one is continent scale and other is small catchment) and then convert it to shapefile

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth, kmz

I am using geological map of South America (source: https://www2.sgc.gov.co/MGC/Paginas/gmsa_google_earth.aspx) to extract the geological map for a small catchment. Initially I converted the KMZ file to KML file for the only feature "continental raster tiles" through Google Earth and also converted my catchment shp to KML, opened them in Google Earth tried copying the large continent map to catchment map (like in QGIS copying the features). It didn't work. Is there any other way I can do it?

Note: I tried exporting the KML file of continent geology to QGIS it is taking eternity to load the file (KML file is 5 mb). I also tried online conversion website which didn't give any map also tried Python no map generated.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Having an "and" in the title is a strong indication that your Question is insufficiently focused. Please choose a task (KML merge or KML-to-shapefile), research your options, and [Edit] your Question to reflect what you have tried and where you are stuck ("It didn't work" needs clarity -- *How* didn't it work?)

Comment: Start with a shapefile: https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/60ad3de6d34e4043c850f2bc